# How to use setResultTransformer in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to use  criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); in the below code to remove duplicate rows ?

```
JPATypedQueryVisitor<Entity> visitor = new JPATypedQueryVisitor<Entity>(
                getEntityManager(), getType());
        visitor.visit(sc);
        TypedQuery<Entity> typedQuery = null;
        typedQuery =visitor.getTypedQuery();

        return typedQuery.getResultList();


public TypedQuery<T1> getTypedQuery() {
        builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        cq = builder.createQuery(Book.class);  
        return em.createQuery(cq); 
}
```

Comment: Can't you use builder.createQuery(Book.class).distinct(true)? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#distinct(boolean)

Comment: When i use distinct(true) with order by child attribute it give error that order by attribute is not in the select list.

Comment: Can't see anything in JPA for that. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131845/jpa-fetching-one-to-many. This resorts to Hibernate API though.

Comment: Ok but what is the diff b/w these two way ?

typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
  typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);